# Need to get exact decimal value in the output in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having two kind of decimal numbers as a value in the input xml

Input:

```
<sets>
  <set>
    <total>0.00</total>
  </set>
  <set>
   <total>5787.43</total>
  </set>
</sets>
```

XSL I'm having:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number(number($cur_value), '###,###.00'))"/>
```

When I'm trying the above XSL I'm getting the output for the first set is

```
$.00
$5,787.43
```

When I have tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number(number($cur_value), '###,###0.00'))"/>
```

Output I'm getting:

```
$0.00
$5787.43
```

On the first try the '0' is missing in the output, on the 2nd try comma is getting missing. Expected output is

```
$0.00
$5,787.43
```

Can anyone suggest a code that should cover both the scenario

Comment: If you want an "exact decimal value" then you definitely don't want to be calling `number()` which converts things to `xs:double`. Unfortunately, you don't actually say what the type of $cur_value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#,##0.00
```

as the *picture* argument.

Even better, make it:

```
$#,##0.00
```

and get rid of the `concat()` part. And I don't think you need the `number()` part either.